Does heat render starfruit safe?
Starfruit or Carambole was shown in 2013 to contain caramboxin, a poison to kidneys and nerves. In people with kidney damage it can cause intoxication, seizures, and death due to insufficient excretion. Even the healthy may sustain kidney damage upon consuming large amounts. Starfruit is also high in oxalic acid, like a number of foodstuffs, which is a main contributor to stones.
Now I know that oxalic acid content is reduced by blanching or cooking that leaches it out into the water, to be discarded. But I cannot find anything specifically about reducing caramboxin. Some mitigation is simple as it too is water-soluble (being dialyzable) and is also said to concentrate in the seeds and surrounding flesh. But what about baking for example? What would this amino acid's decomposition temperature and duration be?

So it's large amounts of star fruit ingestion, or smaller amounts on an empty stomach, that can cause issues. I believe moderate amounts should be fine (unless you're an end-stage renal disease patient on hemodialysis, then avoid at all costs). I didn't know any of that until now.

Looks like the vast majority of the effects are due to oxalate rather than caramboxin, as the oxalate damages the kidneys which results in accumulation of the caramboxin in the body, where it causes neurotoxicity, your question implies that the nephrotoxicity is caused by caramboxin.

There has been an enantioselective total synthesis of caramboxin published in April 2024; I would hope to see more research done on it now. Looking at its chemical structure, I would expect its pyrolytic chemistry to differ significantly from its endogenous agonist analogue, phenylalanine (with a pyrolytic half-life of about 2hr at 180°C, and 0.5-1hr at 200°C)

Many toxins, especially small organic molecules like caramboxin, may degrade at elevated temperatures. Heat can break chemical bonds, rendering the molecule less toxic. Soaking and boiling are the most accessible and practical at home, though they are not guaranteed to eliminate all traces of caramboxin - I didn't find any study with enough information to conclude it's a safe method.
Baking should be less effective than boiling or pressure cooking, since there’s no leaching of the water-soluble toxin.
For individuals with normal kidney function, moderate consumption is generally safe, but for vulnerable populations, processed star fruit products (industrially treated) may be safer options.
I couldn't find any foolproof method to fully deactivate this toxin. It's possible that long lacto-fermentation or enzymatic/chemical neutralization could work, but there are also no known studies. So far there's no effective method to render starfruit free (or down to safe levels) of the caramboxin toxin.

So are you saying that boiling temperatures are capable of partially deactivating caramboxin? Or are you speaking in generalities?

@Sneftel toxins in general, including caramboxin. But there is no info on what temperature / how much can be eliminated, so I didn't add any to the answer.

So if someone is trying to avoid caramboxin for safety reasons, should they feel comfortable using the suggestions you've given?

Thanks for looking into it. I leave the question open in case more becomes known in future. Do you have references with specifics about ferementation's effect on toxins?

@Sneftel I didn't find any info on safety, I edited my answer to include that. I wouldn't recommend anyone to gamble with it.
